Making a JTextPane multiline
How do I make a JTextPane multiline?
That is, I want to achieve the same effect as if it was a JTextArea with wrapStyleWord set to true
It's important that the class remains a JTextPane. A "downgrade" to a regular JTextArea is not acceptable in our application
However, JTextPane doesn't have such a property (not directly, at least)
import javax.swing.*;

// no wrapping yet
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        myPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        JTextPane myTextPane = new JTextPane();
        myTextPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        myTextPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 40));
        myPanel.add(myTextPane);
        frame.add(myPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


Here's what I tried. It doesn't necessarily achieve what I want (as I want the cursor to jump to the next line, stretching the "text area" with no scrollbars), but it sort of deals with the issue of text going beyond the visible area
JScrollPane myScrollableTextPane = new JScrollPane(myTextPane);
myScrollableTextPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
myScrollableTextPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
myPanel.add(myScrollableTextPane);


UPD: If I understood VGR's answer correctly, I have to modify my MRE as follows
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        myPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        JTextPane myTextPane = new JTextPane() {
            @Override
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
                return true;
            }
        };
        myTextPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        myTextPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 40));
        JScrollPane myScrollableTextPane = new JScrollPane(myTextPane);
        myPanel.add(myScrollableTextPane);
        frame.add(myPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

But it produces the exact same result as pictured on my second screenshot. Or, if I paste his/her code directly (downsizing a bit)

His/her second snippet:

Remember what I'm trying to achieve

I want the cursor to jump to the next line, stretching the "text area" with no scrollbars


A JTextPane accepts simple HTML 3.2.  You would place manual breaks in the text.  You can also extend a JTextPane and add the word wrap functionality.

@GilbertLeBlanc manual breaks is a far cry from what I'm looking for. Please revisit the original question. "You can also extend a JTextPane and add the word wrap functionality" The question is how?

Is there a limit on how tall the field can be?  If the user enters 100 rows of text, do you still wish to have no vertical scrollbar?  What will happen to the layout of the window?

@VGR well, we could have some reasonable limit. Though, the user is unlikely to go that nuts

And when that limit is reached, what should happen?  Should a vertical scrollbar appear?

@VGR Yeah. But again, you may assume it will never happen

I remember, years ago, the dev team for the Pidgin messenger client had an epic fight about whether the text entry box should expand automatically, or should have a constant size and should only be resizable by the user.  (Wish I could find the link for it.)  Ultimately they went with the same thing you’re trying to do.  But I don’t agree with the decision, and even now, it irritates me that Discord clients do it.  Consider having something that is always two or three rows high, and use a JSplitPane to let the user decide if they want it to be a different height.

@VGR that would be an unnecessary burden on the user, imo

Answer has been updated.

This can be accomplished by creating a subclass of JTextPane that overrides getScrollableTracksViewportWidth():
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return true;
    }
};

Full example program:
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit;

public class WrappingTextPane {
    void show() {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

            @Override
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        textPane.getActionMap().put("bold",
            new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction());
        textPane.getActionMap().put("italic",
            new StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction());
        textPane.getActionMap().put("underline",
            new StyledEditorKit.UnderlineAction());

        textPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl B"), "bold");
        textPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl I"), "italic");
        textPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl U"), "underline");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wrapping TextPane");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(textPane));
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new WrappingTextPane().show());
    }
}

If you want to make the JTextPane have a reasonable initial size, like a JTextArea would have, you can use a CardLayout with an unseen JTextArea that will determine the CardLayout’s (and thus, the JTextPane’s) size:
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.CardLayout;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit;

public class WrappingTextPane {
    void show() {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

            @Override
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        textPane.getActionMap().put("bold",
            new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction());
        textPane.getActionMap().put("italic",
            new StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction());
        textPane.getActionMap().put("underline",
            new StyledEditorKit.UnderlineAction());

        textPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl B"), "bold");
        textPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl I"), "italic");
        textPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl U"), "underline");

        JTextArea sizer = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        JPanel textPanePanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        textPanePanel.add(new JScrollPane(textPane), "textPane");
        textPanePanel.add(new JScrollPane(sizer), "sizer");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wrapping TextPane");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(textPanePanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new WrappingTextPane().show());
    }
}

Update:
I understand that what you want isn’t just a word wrapping JTextPane.  You want a word wrapping JTextPane that self-expands, much like a lot of chat clients (such as Discord) do.
I believe this can be done by adding a DocumentListener which updates the rows property of the unseen JTextArea, then revalidating.  To determine how many lines the JTextPane’s content uses, we can use the getPositionBelow method of javax.swing.text.Utilities.
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Utilities;

import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class ExpandingWrappingTextPane {
    private static final int MAX_VISIBLE_ROWS =
        Math.max(1, Integer.getInteger("maxrows", 10));

    void show() {
        JTextArea sizer = new JTextArea(5, 20);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

            @Override
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return sizer.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
            }
        };

        textPane.getActionMap().put("bold",
            new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction());
        textPane.getActionMap().put("italic",
            new StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction());
        textPane.getActionMap().put("underline",
            new StyledEditorKit.UnderlineAction());

        textPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl B"), "bold");
        textPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl I"), "italic");
        textPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl U"), "underline");

        JScrollPane sizerScrollPane = new JScrollPane(sizer);
        JScrollPane textScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);

        JPanel textPanePanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        textPanePanel.add(textScrollPane, "textPane");
        textPanePanel.add(sizerScrollPane, "sizer");

        textPane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
                updateSize();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
                updateSize();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
                updateSize();
            }

            private void updateSize() {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                    int lineCount = 1;

                    int len = textPane.getDocument().getLength();
                    int pos = 0;
                    try {
                        while (pos < len && lineCount < MAX_VISIBLE_ROWS) {
                            int posBelow =
                                Utilities.getPositionBelow(textPane, pos, 0f);
                            if (posBelow < 0 || posBelow == pos) {
                                break;
                            }
                            pos = posBelow;
                            lineCount++;
                        }
                    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                        // Assume we've reached the end of the document.
                    }

                    if (sizer.getRows() != lineCount) {
                        sizer.setRows(lineCount);

                        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                            textScrollPane.setMaximumSize(
                                sizerScrollPane.getPreferredSize());

                            if (textPanePanel.getParent() != null) {
                                textPanePanel.getParent().revalidate();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wrapping TextPane");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new JTable()));
        frame.getContentPane().add(textPanePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        textPane.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new ExpandingWrappingTextPane().show());
    }
}

